# knockout observablearry not working

Tags: knockout.js

started learn about Knockout and i saw some tutorials in the below link 
http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections

i have the following code on the page

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
            <td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
```

and if i change the above code like this

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal().mealName, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
            <td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
```

if i change to the value as **value: meal().mealName**  in **Step 3 of 5** it is not working properly, and i'm not getting the proper output. Where the     **Surcharge** id depends on the meal name but if i  directly give as **meal().mealName** it is not working what went wrong and can any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the non-editable field 'mealName' as the value in your code, which it states on the tutorial -

```
// Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
self.availableMeals = [
    { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
    { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
    { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
];
```

The value binding is where you set what the selected value of the select element should be.  Meal name is not an observable property, and therefore it breaks.